# Is hacking my own account illegal?

Tags: email, penetration-test

I have just learned email hacking and I want to test it.

I am well aware that if I hack into any email account, there are chances that my email service provider will track me. So if I hack into my own account, will it be considered illegal?

General illegal cracking definition is - If you are hacking into a person's account **without his consent** , then you are convicting a crime.

But since I am hacking my own account, it's obviously by consent.

Comment: Do you own the server and the hardware and the bandwidth, or is your account hosted on someone else's server/hardware/bandwidth?

Comment: I'm no legal expert but in general you should not attack anything unless you own the servers and hardware, or get express permission from the email provider.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about law, not information security.

Comment: It's hosted on someone's else server

Comment: You are not hacking your own email account; you are hacking a service or application belonging to someone else, where you have permission to use an account. You don't actually own your emails in most places unless you are running your own smtp server; your email provider does.